# SQL Find consecutive numbers in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to the one shown. It contains a list of user ids, the hour value for each hour of the day and an Avail flag to determine if that user is available on that hour.

I need to list all User ids which are  available for a number of consecutive hours defined as @n

```
#####################
# UID # Avail # Hour#
#####################
# 123 #   1   #  0  #
# 123 #   1   #  1  #
# 123 #   0   #  2  #
# 123 #   0   #  3  #
# 123 #   0   #  4  #
# 123 #   1   #  5  #
# 123 #   1   #  6  #
# 123 #   1   #  7  #
# 123 #   1   #  8  #
# 341 #   1   #  0  #
# 341 #   1   #  1  #
# 341 #   0   #  2  #
# 341 #   1   #  3  #
# 341 #   1   #  4  #
# 341 #   0   #  5  #
# 341 #   1   #  6  # 
# 341 #   1   #  7  #
# 341 #   0   #  8  #
######################
```

This should result in the following output for @n=3

```
#######
# UID #
#######
# 123 #
#######
```

I have attempted to use the 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UID,Avail ORDER BY UID,Hour)
to assign a number to each row partitioned by the UID and Whether or not they are flagged as available. However this does not work as the periods of availability may change multiple times a day and the ROW_NUMBER() function was only keeping two counts per user based on the Avail flag.

Comment: [Lead/Lag analytics](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/)  looking at your example why is 123 in the result? 5,7,8 are not consecutive ...  or does 0 mean they are available and 2,3,4 would be the "consecutive" group?

Comment: Sorry, error on my part which i have sorted in the example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2012+ you could using a windowed SUM, but you have to specify the number of rows in the window frame in advance as it won't accept variables so it's not that flexible:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select distinct 
       UID, 
       SUM(avail) over (partition by uid 
                        order by hour 
                        rows between current row and 2 following
                       ) count 
    from table1
)
select uid from cte where count = 3;
```

If you want flexibility you could make it a stored procedure and use dynamic SQL to build and execute the statement, something like this:

```
create procedure testproc (@n int) as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = concat('
    ;with cte as 
    (
       select distinct 
          UID, 
          SUM(avail) over (partition by uid 
                        order by hour 
                        rows between current row and ', @n - 1 , ' following
                        ) count 
       from table1
    )
    select uid from cte where count = ' , @n , ';')
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

and execute it using `execute testproc 3`

An even more inflexible solution is to use correlated subqueries, but then you have to add another subquery for each added count:

```
select distinct uid 
from Table1 t1
where Avail = 1
  and exists (select 1 from Table1 where Avail = 1 and UID = t1.UID and Hour = t1.Hour + 1)
  and exists (select 1 from Table1 where Avail = 1 and UID = t1.UID and Hour = t1.Hour + 2);
```

And yet another way, using row_number to find islands and then filtering by sum of avail for each island:

```
;with c as (
    select 
       uid, avail, 
       row_number() over (partition by uid order by hour) 
       - row_number() over (partition by uid, avail order by hour) grp
from table1
)

select uid from c
group by uid, grp
having sum(avail) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This works...
It does a self join on userID and anything in 2nd table with in @n (3hr) then returns only those records having a count of 3 records.

```
SELECT A.UID
FROM foo A
INNER JOIN foo B
 on A.UId = B.UID
 and A.Hour+3 <= B.Hour
 and A.Avail= 1 and B.Avail=1
GROUP BY A.UID
HAVING count(distinct B.hour) =3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f97ee

Comment: Wasn't 3 just an example?

Comment: The first one doesn't quite work though, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67256/1 and neither does the second version (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c75140/1)

Comment: 3 in the above can be substituted for variable.

Comment: corrected 1st example. dropped 2nd yours is better :P

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have time to polish this ... but this is one option.

- First CTE (c) creates the new column Id
- Second CTE (mx) gets the max row number since you cannot use aggregates in recursive CTEs
- Final CTE (rc) is where the meat is.

  ```
  ;WITH c AS (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [UID],[Hour]) Id, 
          [UID],Avail,[Hour]
      FROM #tmp
  ), mx AS (
      SELECT MAX(Id) MaxRowCount FROM c
  ), rc AS (

      SELECT Id, [UID], Avail, [Hour], c.Avail AS CummulativeHour
      FROM c
      WHERE Id = 1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT c.Id, c.[UID], c.Avail, c.[Hour], CASE WHEN rc.Avail = 0 OR c.Avail = 0 OR rc.[UID] <> c.[UID] THEN c.Avail
                                                  WHEN rc. Avail = 1 AND c.Avail = 1 THEN rc.CummulativeHour + 1 END AS CummulativeHour
      FROM rc
      JOIN c
          ON rc.Id + 1 = c.Id
      WHERE c.Id <= (SELECT mx.MaxRowCount FROM mx)

  )
  SELECT * FROM rc
  ```

Here is the sample data creation...

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([UID] INT, Avail INT, [Hour] INT)

INSERT INTO #tmp
        ( UID, Avail, Hour )
VALUES  (123,1,0),
(123,1,1),
(123,0,2),
(123,0,3),
(123,0,4),
(123,1,5),
(123,1,7),
(123,1,8),
(341,1,0),
(341,0,2),
(341,1,3),
(341,1,4),
(341,0,5),
(341,1,6),
(341,1,7),
(341,0,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main query with several CTE below give you several possibility in order to show what you need (max per user, user with N hours, etc.). Just update the last query below the CTE.

Create table and data:

```
declare @hours table(
uid int
, avail bit
, h tinyint
)
insert into @hours(uid, avail, h) values 
(123, 1, 0),
(123, 1, 1),
(123, 0, 2),
(123, 0, 3),
(123, 0, 4),
(123, 1, 5),
(123, 1, 6),
(123, 1, 7),
(123, 1, 8),
(341, 1, 0),
(341, 1, 1),
(341, 0, 2),
(341, 1, 3),
(341, 1, 4),
(341, 0, 5),
(341, 1, 6), 
(341, 1, 7),
(341, 0, 8),
(341, 1, 23) -- loop through midnight
```

Last row has been added to show that it can detect continuous hours around midnight (see back cte). i.e. 23 => 2AM for uid 341

Query MAX continous hours per user:

```
-- remove duplicate, wrong hours and not available hours
;with hs as (
    Select distinct uid, h from @hours where avail = 1 and h < 24 
), loop(uid, first, last, diff) as (
    --loop through successive hours
    select uid, cast(h as tinyint), cast(h+1 as int), cast(1 as int) from hs
    union all
    select l.uid, l.first, l.last+1, l.diff+1 from loop as l
    inner join hs as h on l.uid = h.uid and l.last = h.h
), back(uid, first, last, diff) as (
    -- search for successive hours around midnight
    select uid, first, last, diff from loop
    union
    select l1.uid, l1.first, l2.last, l1.diff+l2.diff from loop as l1
    inner join loop as l2 on l1.uid = l2.uid and l1.last = 24 and l2.first = 0
), mx(uid, diff) as (
    -- get max continuous hours per user
    select uid, max(diff) from back group by uid
)
-- main query, change it based on what you need (see below)
select b.uid, b.first, b.last, b.diff from back as b
inner join mx as m on m.uid = b.uid and m.diff = b.diff
order by uid, diff desc
```

results:

```
uid first   last    diff
123 5       9       4
341 23      2       3 <= present because I added 341/1/23. Would not be here otherwise
```

Get user with at least 3 continuous hours (replace last select with this one):

```
select distinct uid from back where diff >= 3 -- @n goes here
```

Please not that I considered that (123, 1, 5) give 1 available hour from 5 to 6. Therefore 5 to 8 gives you 4 available hours from 5 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL CODE**

```
create temporary table rank_test(
val numeric)

insert into rank_test select 1;
insert into rank_test select 2;
insert into rank_test select 3;
insert into rank_test select 6;
insert into rank_test select 7;
insert into rank_test select 9;
insert into rank_test select 11;
insert into rank_test select 14;
insert into rank_test select 15;


select val,row_number() over (partition by vno order by val) from (
select val,val-row_number() over (order by val) as vno
from rank_test)a
```

**Output**

```
    A   | Consecutiveness
--------+--------
    1   | 1
    2   | 2
    4   | 1
    6   | 1
    7   | 2
    9   | 1
   11   | 1
   14   | 1
   15   | 2
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**